# ARM Assembly - Writing to Memory - Segmentation Fault

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi

Having a problem writing to memory with ARM Assembly.

I'm using a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) and using GNU Assembler.

first.s :

```
.global main
.func main

main:
    ldr r5, =0x10000000
    mov r1, #19 
    str r1, [r5]
    bx lr
```

When I run the above:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/assembly $ make first
as -o first.o first.s
gcc -o first first.o
pi@raspberrypi ~/assembly $ ./first ; echo $? > output.txt
Segmentation fault
```

As you see, segmentation fault. The output.txt file holds value 139, which I understand refers to the segmentation fault.
Is the memory address not valid?
I've checked the [datasheet](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) and the memory address SEEMS right.

Comment: If you are running under an OS, you only have a virtual address and can't access physical memory or memory mapped devices directly.

Comment: Are you saying there is no way for me to write to memory, or that I am doing it the wrong way?

Comment: No way to write to arbitrary physical memory. You can of course allocate memory for your stuff and then use that. For example you can do `.lcomm myint, 4` and then `ldr r5, =myint`.

Comment: @Jester, thanks for the suggestion. I haven't used .lcomm before, but i'm not sure it would suit my needs. What I really want to do is write the contents of a register to memory, then read the value at that memory location from a seperate C function. I'm assuming there's no way for the C funtion to know the location which .lcomm has reserved... Apologies for the left turn. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: You can then use `.comm` instead, and declare it `extern int myint` in your C code. You can of course also switch to `.data` and use any of the various data definition directives if you also mark the variable `.global`, or define your int in C code and reference it from the asm.

Comment: OK - I'll go off and give that a shot. Thanks again @Jester. Hope you don't mind if I post here with a follow up question later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73664/discussion-between-foaf-and-jester).

Answer (score 0):

There are several different "types" of memory spaces. On a Windows system, for example, there are uncommitted, reserved, read only, executable, etc. Writing to any part of memory that is not marked as "reserved", or an address that does not point to a valid memory address, will result in a seg fault. This is a key security feature of most modern systems. My guess would be that you need to reserve the memory prior to writing to it in order to succeeded in your endeavors.

The easiest way to reserve memory in assembly would be to create a data segment. In many assembly languages, the data segment is proceeded by .data, but I have not used ARM assembly in a very long time to please verify that. Once you have a bit of memory reserved in a data segment, you can easily get the address of the "variable" and write to it just as you have done in your example.